# Multiple media queries

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am trying to style my navbar using media queries using bootstrap. If the screen is between the size of xs and sm then it should be `nav-justified`. If it is larger than it should be `navbar-nav`.

I have done the following:

```
@media (min-width: $screen-md-min) {
  .nav {
    @extend .navbar-nav;
  }
}

@media (min-width: $screen-xs-min) and (max-width: $screen-sm-max){
  .nav {
    @extend .nav-justified;
  }
}
```

Surprisingly this works well independently.

[Nav Justified Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PO3t.png)

However when combined:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONkzK.png)

Any thoughts on how I should do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong.

```
 @media (min-width: $screen-xs-min) and (max-width: $screen-sm-max)
```

Basically will include since **extra small** screen to **small**.

```
 @media (min-width: $screen-md-min)
```

Will start from medium. Leaving **small** to **medium** without any rule.

The right way should be:

```
 @media (min-width: $screen-xs-min) and (max-width: $screen-sm-max)
```

And

```
 @media (min-width: $screen-sm-max)
```

Comment: Sorry it still does not solve the issue. I have included an image to show you the expected output.